# Basic Binding in MVVM Light?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I am wondering how do you do basic binding in MVVM Light.

Say I want to add a Product

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
}
```

My form will only add one product at a time. I see observable collection but I don't need a collection.

How should be ViewModel look like?

Should I just have

```
   public Product Product{ get; set; }
```

then bind each of the properties in Product to the textboxes?

If so then how do I get those values out later?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the value in the view model can change or not. 
If it can, then the view model needs to raise the PropertyChanged event. I believe that MVVM light has a code snippet to help with that.

Now, if the UI needs to change the value in the view model, then the binding needs to be two-way.

Comment: Well the user would enter in the value and it should be saved into that object. No default values would be shown so it would be Ui -> object.

Comment: Then it would still be a two-way binding. It's just that the viewmodel wouldn't populate the string.